# How to add a constraint only if does not exist while Alter tabel, in postgress

Tags: postgresql, constraints, ddl, flyway

```
ALTER TABLE large_payout_clearance_slip_type_threshold_limit
DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS large_payout_clearance_slip_type_threshold_limit_un_clearance_i;

ALTER TABLE public.large_payout_clearance_slip_type_threshold_limit 
 ADD CONSTRAINT large_payout_clearance_slip_type_threshold_limit_slip_type_clearance_id UNIQUE (slip_type,large_payout_clearance_id) If NOT Exist;
```

If not exist is not working, what should be done ideally here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) there simply isn't a `if not exists` option when adding a constraint.

Comment: then how we formulate the if not exist condition or to restrict adding of constraint , if it already exist

Comment: If it  does not exist when you will get an error, so be it. Ignore it and move on.  No need for a not exists condition,